# Facebook integrated app is not logging out after logging out from native app in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have developed a facebook integrated app. In the app, first i logout from native facebook app. Then launch my app. It will ask for facebook credentials. Provide the details. It will log in and display my user name. Now close the app and launch it again. It will not ask for facebook credentials again, automatically logged in. Till this, it is behaving proper.

Only issue is coming when i am logged out from the native app, it is not logging out from my app. It is still carrying the previous logged in session. How can i change this behavior..

I am using the below code:

```
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

          Log.d("Testing", "session opened  "+session.isOpened());
          Log.d("Testing", "session closed  "+session.isClosed());
          if (session.isOpened()) {

            // make request to the /me API
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

              // callback after Graph API response with user object
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

//                  Log.d("Testing", "user null or not  "+(user == null));
                if (user != null) {
                  TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
                  Log.d("Testing", "user name:::  "+user.getName());
                  welcome.setText("Hello "+user.getName() + "!");
                }
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });



    }
      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
```

Thanks,
Arindam

Comment: on destroy you clear the session and token information

Comment: It worked..   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onDestroy();
     Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }

Comment: Accepted as answer. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override protected void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onDestroy();
Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
}
```